# Bluetooth sound going the wrong way between Linux and projector

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, kde

OK, this seems like a dumb problem...

I paired a Kubuntu PC to an Android TV projector. I wanted to play some music on the PC and hear it on the (good sound quality) projector. I already do that between my phone and the projector... But here the sound is going the wrong way: sound from the projector are played on the PC puny speakers !

I don't see any options to change direction in the KDE Bluetooth options.

Comment: Does the projector remote have a button for loudspeaker selection?

Comment: I don't think so. On the box there's Power/-/+/Play. On the remote there are the usual Android buttons and arrows. I've looked at the bluetooth menus and see nothing in there.